# SQL Query to Append Past Order with Most Recent Order

Tags: sql-server, datetime, max

I have an order table that has both past membership data and current data. I want to view this data in single row. I have a temp table for past data, but not exactly sure how to write this query to get current data in the same row. I know it has something to do with the `MAX(order no)`. Here is the query to get the past membership data in a temp table

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted

declare 
@ship_master_customer_id varchar (10),  @cycle_begin_date datetime,  @cycle_end_date datetime,  @OrderNo varchar(10), @Description Char(100)

create table #t1(ShipMasterCustomerID varchar(10),  OrderNo varchar (10), cycle_begin_date datetime,  cycle_end_date datetime,  Description Char(100))

Insert into #t1 

Select SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_NO, CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE,CYCLE_END_DATE, DESCRIPTION FROM [ORDER_DETAIL]

where SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = '11115555' and 
CYCLE_END_DATE = '2/29/2016'

Select * from #t1
Drop table #t1



Here is my script. 

    declare 
    @ship_master_customer_id varchar (10),  @cycle_begin_date datetime,  @cycle_end_date datetime,  @OrderNo varchar(10), @Description Char(100)

    create table #t2(ShipMasterCustomerID varchar(10),  OrderNo varchar (10), cycle_begin_date datetime,  cycle_end_date datetime,  Description Char(100))

    Insert into #t2 (shipmastercustomerid, orderno, cycle_begin_date, cycle_end_date, DESCRIPTION)

    VALUES (1111555,9004731815, 2015/01/01, 2015/31/12,'Annual Mem'), 
    (1111555, 9005148308, 2016/01/01, 2016/31/12,'Annual Mem'), 
    (1111222, 9005027152, 2015/01/03, 2016/29/02,'Annual Mem'), 
    (1111222, 9005440369, 2016/01/03, 2017/31/03,'Annual Mem'),
    (2223333, 9005027152, 2014/01/01, 2016/31/12,'Annual Mem'), 
    (2223333, 9005442116, 2016/01/01, 2017/31/12,'Annual Mem')

Select * from #t2

Drop table #t2
```

[image]

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9z9b.png)

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL here. You seem to be looking at orders information yet you have the isolation level as read uncommitted. Are you ok with randomly getting missing and/or duplicate rows? It can and will happen. If accuracy is important don't do this. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: What would really help here is some sample data. You have a table variable and a temp table. You even have an insert into the temp table...however the source of the insert is a table we don't have.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to upload a sample excel now.

Comment: apparently i can't upload a file on here.

Comment: A file is NOT sample data. You should post a create table statement and the insert statements to populate it using hard coded values.

Comment: I'm still a sql beginner so i cant figure out why my dates are displaying as outlined, but here is the script.

Comment: Your dates are all out whack because they are not wrapped in single quotes. As a result what is happening it is treated like a number first, so it does the multiple levels of division and then adds that many days to 1900-01-01. When coding dates you should use the ISO format of yyyy-mm-dd. To make this work you will have to set the dateformat with "set dateformat ydm" after you wrap those dates with single quotes.

Comment: But then the challenge get worse. You have sample output but none of the data matches the sample data you provided. As of right now your question is pretty much in an unanswerable state.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a temp table.  You can query the same table twice, giving it an alias and then use the alias to prefix your column names.  Since you didn't give us a complete schema or a fiddle I'm simulating your database with a temp table but the essence is here.  There are considerations that you didn't mention, though.  Are you guaranteed that every customer will have both a historical AND a current record?  If not, they will not appear in the query below because of the INNER JOIN.  You could change it to an OUTER join but when customers don't have a new record you will see NULL values in those columns.  My point is that here be dragons... this is by no means a complete or bulletproof solution, only a nudge in the right direction.

```
DECLARE @ORDER_DETAIL AS TABLE(
    ShipMasterCustomerId varchar(20),
    OrderNo varchar(20),
    cycle_begin_date date,
    cycle_end_date date,
    Description varchar(100)
)

INSERT @ORDER_DETAIL SELECT '11115555', '9005337015', '02/26/15', '2/29/16', 'Membership 26-Feb-2015 to 29-Feb-2016'
INSERT @ORDER_DETAIL SELECT '11115555', '9005743023', '02/28/17', '2/28/17', 'Membership 01-Mar-2016 to 28-Feb-2017'

SELECT 
    hist.ShipMasterCustomerId, 
    hist.OrderNo, 
    hist.cycle_begin_date,
    hist.CYCLE_END_DATE, 
    hist.[Description],
    curr.ShipMasterCustomerId, 
    curr.OrderNo, 
    curr.cycle_begin_date,
    curr.CYCLE_END_DATE, 
    curr.[Description]
FROM 
    @ORDER_DETAIL AS hist 
    INNER JOIN @ORDER_DETAIL AS curr ON (
            (curr.ShipMasterCustomerId = hist.ShipMasterCustomerId) AND (curr.cycle_end_date = 
            (SELECT MAX(cycle_end_date) FROM @ORDER_DETAIL WHERE ShipMasterCustomerId = hist.ShipMasterCustomerId))
            )
WHERE 
    (hist.ShipMasterCustomerId = '11115555') 
    AND 
    (hist.cycle_end_date = '2/29/2016')
```

Comment: Thank you! How can i scale this query? The reason i used the cycle end date is i get the total count of memberships that ended on specific date and finding the MAX order number for  any SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID tells me if they renewed or not.

Comment: You'll have to define "scale" first.  Do you only want to show customers who have never renewed (only 1 record in the db), customers who may have renewed in the past but didn't renew in the last year, etc?  You need to give us more information.